# Selenium Remote Webdriver gives JSONDecodeError

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

My code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common import desired_capabilities

class test_mycode(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_cap = {'browser': 'IE', 'browser_version': '8.0', 'os': 'Windows', 'os_version': '7', 'resolution': '1366x768'}
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://username:ACCESS_KEY@hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=desired_cap)

    def test_website(self):    
    .....
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Workspace\Pumpkin Patch Website\test cases\_test_mycode.py", line 55, in setUp
    desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
File "C:\Users\elton.tiong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "C:\Users\elton.tiong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
File "C:\Users\elton.tiong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\elton.tiong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 102, in check_response
    value = json.loads(value_json)
File "C:\Users\elton.tiong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\elton.tiong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\elton.tiong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

selenium-server-standalone2.48.0 is installed and running.

Python is 3.5

This is the code I wrote to run Selenium on Browserstack. I followed the instructions given by Browserstack, however, when I run it, it raised JSONDecodeError.

I also changed the command_executor to http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub but it failed. Then I changed the desire_capabilities=desired_cap to desired_capabilities.DesireCapabilities.FIREFOX but it also fail.

I googled everywhere but cannot find any answer. Can someone please help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 2 years old, but since no one answered, hopefully this will be helpful to someone else. The value in the `desired_cap` is basically an invalid json. To confirm, I ran it against https://jsonlint.com/.

The fix is simple - replace all the single quotes to double quotes:

```
desired_cap = {'browser': 'IE', 'browser_version': '8.0', 'os': 'Windows', 'os_version': '7', 'resolution': '1366x768'}
desired_cap = desired_cap.replace('\\'', '\\"')
```

Comment: Old followup but this fixed my issue... why though? Are single vs double quotes not interchangeable in Python?